# ViPER4Android not processing

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-j7, equalizer

After a couple of times of trying many solutions I found on the internet, I still couldn't fix the problem.  I think, I have tried almost everything.

---

Actually, before this problem, I also have one more problem, which is now fixed.  That problem is that the `Driver Status` is "Abnormal", and the `Audio Format` is "Unsupported", like this:

```
Driver Version: 2.5.0.4
NEON Enabled: No
Enabled: No
Status: Abnormal
Audio Format: Unsupported
Processing: No
Sampling Rate: 0
```

Well, that problem is fixed now ([solution here](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/install-viper4android-nougat/)), but I still got a problem.

---

ViPER4Android is not processing, even if I'm playing a song.  I'm pretty sure that the music player that I'm using is supported.  I am using Google Play Music as my music player.

The problem is that, whatever I change (a setting) on ViPER4Android, it is still the same.  It doesn't do anything, but the stock equalizer does.  The stock equalizer is still working, which should be not.

Here is the driver status:

```
Driver Status: 2.5.0.4
NEON Enabled: Yes
Enabled: Yes
Status: Normal
Audio Format: Supported
Processing: No
Sampling Rate: 48000
```

---

Some things you might ask:

**Have you tried turning it off and on again? (ViPER4Android):**   Yes.
**Have you tried turning it off and on again? (Android device):**   Yes.
**Have you tried disabling the stock equalizer? :**   I "tried", but it didn't work.
**What sites have you found on the internet for solutions? :**   I can't remember 'cause there are a lot, but it's mostly on [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/).
**Have you flashed a flashable zip? :**   Yes.
**What device are you using? :**   See below.

---

Device:

> Device:   Samsung Galaxy J7 Core
>
> Model Number:   SM-J701F/DS
>
> Android version:   7.0 Nougat
>
> ROM:   Stock ROM
>
> Recovery: TWRP
>
> Rooted:   *Of course!*

Comment: This is a common issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is found on "audio_effects.conf", which contains unnecessary things that needs to be removed and some to be changed, in order for it to worked.

> For Samsung devices, "audio_effects.conf" is found in `/system/etc`.

---

## Remove these:

**Libraries**:

```
output_session_processing {
  path /vendor/lib/libLifevibes_lvverx.so
}

mysound {
  path /system/lib/libmysound.so
}

myspace {
  path /system/lib/soundfx/libmyspace.so
}

soundalive {
  path /system/lib/libaudiosa.so
}

soundalive_sec {
  path /system/lib/soundfx/libaudiosaplus_sec.so
}

soundbooster_plus {
  path /system/lib/libsamsungSoundbooster_plus.so
}
```

**Effects**:

```
soundalive {
  library soundalive_sec
  uuid cf65eb39-ce2f-48a8-a903-ceb818c06745
}

lmfv {
  library output_session_processing
  uuid 989d9460-413d-11e1-8b0d-0002a5d5c51b
}

fens {
    library output_session_processing
    uuid cbcc5980-476d-11e1-82ee-0002a5d5c51b
}

dha {
  library mysound
  uuid 263a88e0-50b1-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66
}

sa3d {
  library myspace
  uuid 3462a6e0-655a-11e4-8b67-0002a5d5c51b
}

soundbooster_plus {
  library soundbooster_plus
  uuid 50de45f0-5d4c-11e5-a837-0800200c9a66
}
```

**Output Session Processing**:

```
output_session_processing {
  music {
      sa3d {}
  }

  ring {
      sa3d {}
  }

  voice_call {
      fens {}
      lmfv {}
  }

  sec_voice_communication {
      fens {}
      lmfv {}
  }
}
```

---

## Change these:

**Libraries**:

From:

```
pre_processing {
  path /vendor/lib/libLifevibes_lvvetx.so
}
```

To:

```
pre_processing {
  path /system/lib/soundfx/libaudiopreprocessing.so
}
```

**Effects**:

From:

```
bassboost {
  library soundalive
  uuid a926a540-418a-11e1-b2f1-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

To:

```
bassboost {
  library bundle
  uuid 8631f300-72e2-11df-b57e-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

From:

```
virtualizer {
  library soundalive
  uuid c747f6a0-418a-11e1-a621-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

To:

```
virtualizer {
  library bundle
  uuid 1d4033c0-8557-11df-9f2d-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

From:

```
equalizer {
  library soundalive
  uuid c117b70-f97f-11e0-be50-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

To:

```
equalizer {
  library bundle
  uuid ce772f20-847d-11df-bb17-0002a5d5c51b
}
```

---

> For Samsung devices, after doing those things above, also copy the modified "audio_effects.conf" to `/system/vendor/etc`.